# Refactor a method that it can handle multiple types?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following class:

```
public class Disciplines
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Discipline { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

My project has several view models that use that class to create a checkbox group in the form of:

```
public List<Disciplines> DisciplinesCBG { get; set; }
```

I'm saving the checkbox selections to the database as a comma separated string, and then splitting the string on the comma to re display as checkboxes:

```
public static UserProfileViewModel DisciplinesStringToCheckboxGroup(UserProfileViewModel model)
{
    string[] disciplineArray = model.Disciplines.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < model.DisciplinesCBG.Count; i++)
    {
        string currentValue = model.DisciplinesCBG[i].Discipline;
        if(Array.IndexOf(disciplineArray, currentValue) > -1)
        {
            model.DisciplinesCBG[i].IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

My question is, how can I write the method to be usable for other ViewModel types in addition to `UserProfileViewModel`? For example I have a view model called `RegisterViewModel` that uses the same `public List<Disciplines> DisciplinesCBG { get; set; }` that I would like to be able to use the same method as above without having to just copying it and change the signature. I'm assuming that it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an interface that has `Disciplines` and `DisciplinesCBG` property and then implement it in each classes that you want to apply.

```
interface IHasDiciplines
{
    string Disciplines { get; set; }
    List<Disciplines> DisciplinesCBG { get; set; }
}

class UserProfileViewModel : IHasDiciplines
{
    public string Disciplines { get; set; }
    public List<Disciplines> DisciplinesCBG { get; set; }
}

public static IHasDiciplines DisciplinesStringToCheckboxGroup(IHasDiciplines  model)
{
    string[] disciplineArray = model.Disciplines.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < model.DisciplinesCBG.Count; i++)
    {
        string currentValue = model.DisciplinesCBG[i].Discipline;
        if(Array.IndexOf(disciplineArray, currentValue) > -1)
        {
            model.DisciplinesCBG[i].IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Your last method could also be an extension method. Not sure a simple base class wouldn't be better than the interface in this case.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It can also be a BaseClass, but it will get complicated if later you need to add `HasFoo`, `HasBar`, `HasSomething`.

Comment: Sure, at which point preferring composition to inheritance would seem to become a major factor. Not saying the interface is *wrong*, but interfaces that are "IHaveSomething" is a bit of a red flag